# How to execute an sql file containing statements for multiple databases in online mode?

Tags: mysql, nohup

Recently, one of my requirements have been to modify multiple dbs at one go and i have been using SOURCE command to execute the file (.sql file)

However, i wanted to know if there is an online way to do it because that way i can use nohup to let it run even if i log out or any network issues come along and my session ends. By online mode, i meant not having to go to mysql command line ( mysql> )

Wanted to know if this is possible at all? Please note that SQL file is targeted to modify multiple DBs at one go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about an "online mode", but if you want to let your mysql run even if you log out if a network issue come along, I suggest you use [GNU screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). If your session ends, anything runned inside screen will continue to run in the background, and you'll be able to reattach your session with `screen -r` when you'll signin again.

Comment: Thanks, I missed mentioning i was working on Windows platform, not sure if GNU screen can help me there.